# if/for loop conditioning for multiple strings

Tags: java, string, loops, conditional-statements

I'm new to Java and relatively new to programming. In the code above, I simply need to add some kind of condition which checks if the c String is containing one of the following values : (*,/,+,-,(,),^), and then proceeds with rest of the instructions (from place in code marked as "B")

Other related questions here on the forum haven't helped; Perhaps I'm looking at wrong tool to accomplish this. I have no idea what to do with this, besides using if and copying B section for every value that i'm interested in(not very elegant way, I must admit;))

Help much appreciated!

```
private static void convertOnpToInf(String onp) {
    Stack stack = new Stack();
    try {
        for (int i=0; i<onp.length(); i++) {    
            String c = String.valueOf( onp.charAt(i) );
            if (c.matches("[a-z]+")) {  
                stack.push(c);
```

//B section

```
            } else {    
                if (stack.isEmpty()) {
                    throw new Exception("error");
                }
                String a = stack.pop();
                if (stack.isEmpty()) {
                    throw new Exception("error");
                }
                String b = stack.pop();


                if ( addBracket(convertToOperator(c), onp, i) ) {   
                    stack.push("(" + b + c + a + ")");
                } else {
                    stack.push( b + c + a );
                }
```

Comment: Can you explain this code a little more? Why are you popping the stack twice?

Comment: it's part of bigger program(<ONP> to <INF> converter) - popping the stack twice is part of algorithm but I think it's pretty irrelevant to my problem

Comment: If you need `c` to be equal to `*,/,+,-,(,),^`, why are you matching on at least one char from `a-z` ?

Comment: a-z chars goes onto stack with no other instructions needed. On the other hand, operators(*,/,...) must go through b section to function properly in converter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understand it right. Here are 2 ways to do it:

1:

```
if (onp.charAt(i) == '*' || onp.charAt(i) == '+' || ...) { // all your operators
//B
}
```

2:

```
private static final Set<String> operators = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("*", "+", "-")); // all your operators

        String c = "*";
        if (operators.contains(c)) {
            // B
        }
```